# Java label check image

Tags: java, image, label

I have some labels (10) and I want to remove the listener like this `JLabel.removeMouseListener(this);` when  `Label Image="pirosgomb.jpg"`

*I tried many different ways but I couldn't get it working...*

**edit: Thank You guys, now work, edited code:**

```
if (event.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
              kepstring=((JLabel)event.getSource()).getIcon().toString();

}

            if(kepstring.equals("pirosgomb.jpg")) {

            }else {

                if (x == 1) {
                    ((JLabel)event.getSource()).setIcon(new ImageIcon("zoldgomb.jpg"));
                    x = 2;

                } else if (x == 2) {
                    ((JLabel)event.getSource()).setIcon(new ImageIcon("sargagomb.jpg"));
                    x = 1;

                }
            }
```

Comment: OK now please tell us, where is the issue? where `event.getSource()` is used?

Comment: the issue is that how can i write that if `A1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("pirosgomb.jpg"))` then `A1.removeMouseListener` A1=label name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use the method [`Component.setName(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29)? e.g.:

```
A1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("pirosgomb.jpg"))
A1.setName("pirosgomb.jpg");

if ("pirosgomb.jpg".equals(label.getName()) {
    label.removeMouseListener(this);
}
```

Comment: How come other developers know that name is used as icon url? Not a good design to use `setName` that is designed for other purpose. Think about code readability and maintainability.

Comment: @Braj I agree with you. The best aproach is to use constants for the several icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way.

```
final Icon icon = new ImageIcon("pirosgomb.jpg");
...
JLabel label = ...
label.setIcon(icon);
```

inside the mouse listener:

```
if(label.getIcon() == icon){...}
```

Comment: Can other than you know about it that `getName()` of `JLabel` returns icon's url? Don't use any such method that's not meant for? This breakes the code readability and maintainability.